# @param - what does this symbol do in object oriented php

Tags: php, oop

I was wondering what is the point of @access, @return and @param in a PHP class. I figure it would be easy to understand if someone could explain in simple words.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

These are [phpDocumentor](http://manual.phpdoc.org/) keywords: [@param](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html) and [@access](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.access.pkg.html)

Answer (score 1):

in simple words, it does not affect the code in away, but helps other programmers to generate a documentation or understand what each code is doing, returning, or what parameters it needs.. Some IDEs look for these.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I have a method which retrieves all rows from the database then what would @return be? mixed?

Comment: @user3527939 Yes mixed works for all types. If you parse the result and want to be more specific it could also be an array of strings or ints. You can get more informations here: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html