# Can someone explain the use of @ comments in this PHP class?

Tags: php

I was trying to find an OO way of dealing with databases in PHP, and came across this: https://github.com/adriengibrat/Simple-Database-PHP-Class

Before trying to use it, I'm reading through the code trying to understand exactly what is being done (and failing quite miserably so far).

Along the way I saw comments prefixed with "@" that I'm not used to seeing. Is this something than IDE would add on or is it an OO way of commenting things within a class? Look at this snippet for example:

```
/**
 * Get and set default Db configurations
 * @uses   static::config
 * @param  string|array $key   [Optional] Name of configuration or hash array of configurations names / values
 * @param  mixed        $value [Optional] Value of the configuration
 * @return mixed        Configuration value(s), get all configurations when called without arguments
 */
static public function config ( $key = null, $value = null ) {
    if ( ! isset( $key ) )
        return static::$config;
    if ( isset( $value ) )
        return static::$config[ (string) $key ] = $value;
    if ( is_array( $key ) )
        return array_map( 'static::config', array_keys( (array) $key ), array_values( (array) $key ) );
    if ( isset( static::$config[ $key ] ) )
        return static::$config[ $key ];
}
```

Can someone explain the significance of these comments?

Also, though unrelated to my question, would anyone be able to comment on whether this looks like a good way to deal with databases in an OO fashion? (take a look at the link above to get an idea).

Thanks!

Comment: There's a [**post here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23095973/) actually that you can have a look through.

Comment: http://www.phpdoc.org/ phpDocumentor doc blocks...

Comment: In reality, it's just a garbled way to present what the function is doing in the head of the script without using normal pseudocode throughout the script to explain actions. it's assuming you've been around for awhile in the scripting world and can glance at the logic being used without in-depth commenting.

Comment: @WASasquatch Not, garbled... "machine-readable". Used for generating API documentation from your code, which can be formatted into HTML, or other useful things.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll take a look at the duplicate topics right now. Meanwhile, does anyone have an opinion on this database class I found?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah, for PHPED and other PHP Type Hint reading. Which is not necessary unless you're releasing your code. I have seen this database class used and asked about before, from what I see it's fairly solid. What are you using it for?

Comment: @WASasquatch: I want to build a lightweight framework, mainly for the purpose of learning. I was going to use this as a guideline to create my own DB class.

Comment: @user2930185 Oh, well in that case I would say that is a fine place to start. Don't be shy to lookup what you don't understand in the class, it'll only help broaden the horizons. Let us know if you need anymore help. We're always here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its used primarily for when working with phpDoc. The @ in front of a return or var or param will allow the phpDoc [service](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html) to create an API documentation for your code. None the less using phpDoc or not you should always specify the returns, params, and the var type. Just my opinion.

Comment: It's only meant for releasing your code, like git, etc. If you do not intend to use these services, there is no point but making it easier for others to redistribute your code with it's logic intact and explained. This is why commercial products do not specify PHP Type Hints. And by doing so, while not releasing your code, it's easy for them to claim it as their own with proof built on a github or elsewhere, while you don't.